# Bootstrap Align Label to Pagination

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a pagination element to move to the previous / next page.  I would like to display a label right before it to show current and total item counts.  For example:

**1 - 30** of **2,950** `[ < Prev ]`  `[ Next > ]`

I'm not sure how to get the alignment right.  I also have other buttons / labels in the same row and would like everything middle-aligned.  Here's a screenshot of what I get.

[image]

And, how I want it to appear.

[image]

A plunkr with the code demonstrating the issue:

http://plnkr.co/edit/SaYpq1ov4MPBCGcAUQVt?p=preview

Here's the HTML I'm using.

```
<div ng-cloak class="ng-cloak row" style="margin-bottom: 2em;">
    <span style="margin-right: 2em;">
        <span class="small" style="margin-right: 0.5em;">Folder</span>
        <div class="btn-group">     
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Sent</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Outbox</button>
        </div>      
    </span> 
    ... other buttons and labels are the same layout  ...
    <div class="pull-right">        
        <span class="small" style="margin-right: 0.5em;">
            <strong>1 - 30</strong> of <strong>255</strong>
        </span>
        <ul class="pagination" style="margin: 0px !important;">         
          <li><a>&laquo;</a></li>  
          <li><a>&raquo;</a></li>
        </ul>       
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set `vertical-align: middle;` in the `<ul class="pagination">` element:

```
<ul class="pagination" style="margin: 0px !important; vertical-align: middle;">
```